# Including two html files for two windows in Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I want to create a second window through a button click. I tried creating a second window using IPC in main.js and the window does pop up.

```
ipcMain.on('video', (e) => {
  vidWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      height:500,
      width: 500
  });
  vidWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + './../src/Video.html');
  vidWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  vidWindow.removeMenu();
});
```

I thought I can just include a second html file in the public folder, change the id from "root" to something else ('vid' in my case), and add a second `ReactDOM.render` like so in index.js:

```
const mainElement = document.getElementById('root');
if(mainElement){
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/'><Redirect to='/login'/></Route>
        <Route path='/login'><Login /></Route>
        <Route path='/home'><App /></Route>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    mainElement
  );
}

const vidElement = document.getElementById('vid');
if(vidElement){
  ReactDOM.render(
    <VideoPage/>,
    vidElement
  );
}
```

However, the VideoPage element is not rendered, so I think there must be some misunderstanding on my part about how the Electron rendering process works. I've been stuck on this for days and still can't find a solution to this, unfortunately. Is this the right approach to try to run two windows at the same time?

Comment: Hi there, try without IPC and just use the API.

```window.open('https://github.com', '_blank', 'nodeIntegration=no')```